# object StreamingContext is not a member of package org.apache.spark [error] import org.apache.spark.StreamingContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to run nc wordcount program in spark on SBT,
and i am getting below  error with log my spark version :- 1.6.3
 and scala version is 2.10.0

```
  [warn] Found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
[warn]  * commons-net:commons-net:2.2 is selected over 3.1
[warn]      +- org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:1.6.3             (depends on 2.2)
[warn]      +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.2.0              (depends on 3.1)
[warn]  * com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1 is selected over 11.0.2
[warn]      +- org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:2.4.0           (depends on 14.0.1)
[warn]      +- org.tachyonproject:tachyon-client:0.8.2            (depends on 14.0.1)
[warn]      +- org.apache.curator:curator-client:2.4.0            (depends on 14.0.1)
[warn]      +- org.tachyonproject:tachyon-underfs-hdfs:0.8.2      (depends on 14.0.1)
[warn]      +- org.apache.curator:curator-framework:2.4.0         (depends on 14.0.1)
[warn]      +- org.tachyonproject:tachyon-underfs-s3:0.8.2        (depends on 14.0.1)
[warn]      +- org.tachyonproject:tachyon-underfs-local:0.8.2     (depends on 14.0.1)
[warn]      +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:2.2.0                (depends on 11.0.2)
[warn]      +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.2.0              (depends on 11.0.2)
[warn]  * com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9 is selected over 2.0.1
[warn]      +- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2                      (depends on 1.3.9)
[warn]      +- org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:1.6.3             (depends on 1.3.9)
[warn]      +- org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe_2.10:1.6.3           (depends on 1.3.9)
[warn]      +- org.apache.spark:spark-network-common_2.10:1.6.3   (depends on 1.3.9)
[warn]      +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.10:2.4.4 (depends on 2.0.1)
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/training/Desktop/SBT/sbt/bin/sparknc/target/scala-2.10/classes ...
[error] /home/training/Desktop/SBT/sbt/bin/sparknc/src/main/scala/sparkstreaming.scala:2:8: object StreamingContext is not a member of package org.apache.spark
[error] import org.apache.spark.StreamingContext
[error]        ^
[error] /home/training/Desktop/SBT/sbt/bin/sparknc/src/main/scala/sparkstreaming.scala:6:56: value setApplication is not a member of org.apache.spark.SparkConf
[error] val mysparkconf= new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setApplication("My networking application")
[error]                                                        ^
[error] /home/training/Desktop/SBT/sbt/bin/sparknc/src/main/scala/sparkstreaming.scala:7:27: not found: type StreamingContext
[error] val streamingcontext= new StreamingContext(mysparkconf, seconds(2))
[error]                           ^
```

[error] three errors found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed

Comment: Why do you think that all the version number conflicts have anything to do with it? [StreamingContext](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext) seems to be member of the package `org.apache.spark.streaming`, and has always been, since [version 1.0.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext)?

Comment: this is the Libraray defenition, i gave in build.sbt,

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.3",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.6.3",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.6.3" %
)
and i am not able to figure out why it is giving this error;

Comment: If the project came packaged with a apache spark distribution, then you probably should tag your question as `[apache-spark]`.

Comment: Apology , can u do the edit in the query?

Answer (score 0):

There is need to add the **exact dependency** of spark-streaming into your build.sbt file.

Set scala version  as **2.10.5**

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.6.3" % "provided"
```

Just suggestion use latested spark 2.3.1,with new features most of  the dependency issues resolved

Adding a link for fixed issues[spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-3-0.html)